# Interview question: reverse pairs in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashmap

I got this for my interview: a pair of arrays [a,b],[b,a] are counted as a reverse pair. for example, the input array is [[a,b],[b,a],[a,c],[c,a],[a,b]], and the output is 2 because there are two reversed pairs.
Now I can get the time complexity to be O(n) using a hashmap, is there any way to get better than O(n)?

Comment: Why didn't you count [b,a] and [a,b]?

Comment: It does not make much sense that algorithms run faster than *O(n)*, since we need at least *O(n)* to read the input. The only exceptions are when there is already a datastructure or an assumption we can make on the input (so we did some work before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is simple:

1. you iterate over an array, and count in hashmap the occurence of the pairs, getting the result like `[ [a,b] : 2, [a,c] : 1, [b,a] : 1, ... ]`
2. you iterate over the hashmap, computing the minimum of the occurence of the inversed pairs, for example `[a,b] : 2`, `[b,a] : 1`, so you have `1`.
3. you add the results from step 2, which gives you the final result.

And you cannot do it faster than O(N), because you have to check every element at least once.